# Create a list of user whose home directories have no files newer than 7 years

Tags: linux, scripting, users

I have an old storage with hundreds of user home directories. I want to reclaim some disk space by deleting all "old" home dirs. It's on a linux server, RHEL 6.  I want to delete the entire home dir., but only if there are no files that have been create, modified, updated or accessed, in under 7 years. Does anyone have any idea how to build a script to do this?

Thankyou.

Comment: Using access time may not be reliable, as automated tools such as backup clients may have accessed such old files.

Comment: Thank you pointing out what could be a serious hurdle. At this point, I can hope and pray this will work as I have a lot of data to store.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to author a bash script to do this if you need help with that it might be better asking on Stack Overflow because it's script development.

While this is possible if the distribution used supports `atime` some don't be the default they explicitly mount the filesystem with `noatime` in this case you would not be able to know when the file was last read and only when created or modified (updated is the same thing) the other option that is used but would work for you is `realtime` this would only update the file last accessed normally once per day.

To check this use `ls -l --time=atime` you can then use this in a bash script with `ls -ls --time=atime | while read line`

As I said above that is the tool you need if you need a script building to do this for you I would say you should be on stack overflow and not server fault while this is a server building a script falls more into the programming side than the server management side of the two sites.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried `ls -l --time=atime` and `ls -l` and the output looks the same. Im starting to think atime mite be too much to hope for. I'll try your other suggestion too. I'll repost on Stack Overflow.